# Windows:How to add command as admin via CMD to Right Click?

Tags: cmd

there any way to add a new entry to windows explorer context menu for any file,folder and driver that could run this command as admin?

```
attrib -h -r -a -s /s /d *.*
```

Comment: Do not fool around with this: there are lot of good reasons what for some files and / or folders should keep attributed system, hidden, read-only...

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the registry in CMD and it will show you how to do it, BUT BE CAREFUL THE REGISTRY CAN CORRUPT A PC!